# Making Scatter Plots Smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I was trying to shift my plotting platform from something like Excel to R/ggplot2.

I'm having a difficult time making the scatter plot points join smoothly. I have some data:

```
p1 <- ggplot(DunnTib, aes(Vf, CV3, col = Rsq))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()
p1
```

And the result it generates is something like this:
[ggplot2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6V84.png)

The plot as I made it in Excel was much smoother:
[Excel 2013 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ1NQ.png)

I tried using geom_path() as well as geom_line() and adjusting the size but haven't found a better solution. Any tips on how to achieve the same level of smoothness

**Edit:**
I've shared the complete data on Google Drive [[link]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mX7r7rianwEta4Czp3Gbmrw8qmwY78Ry/view?usp=sharing). The lack of smoothness is more pronounced when a lot of points are used because they are so close together.

I also tried `geom_path()` and while this is the kind of shape I want, a crisper line as it was in Excel would be preferable.

```
p1 <- ggplot(DunnTib, aes(Vf, CV3)) +
  geom_path(size = 2, col = 'red')+
  theme_bw()
p1
```

[geom_path plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXIuj.png)

Edit: I've found a solution to my own question so I thought I'd add it here. What you're looking for is anti-aliasing. ggplot doesn't do anti-aliasing but a package called `Cairo` does. Read about it [here](https://www.roelpeters.be/how-to-anti-alias-plots-in-r/)

Comment: Make `Rsq` a factor. That is, `.. col = as.factor(Rsq))`. Look at the scale, then you see it is numeric.

Comment: @markus I tried that but what I get is a list of swatches with the Rsq (R-Squared) values. I replaced it with `col = 'Red'` and used `geom_path()` and the result is much better in terms of smoothness but still not as much as I was hoping for.

Comment: you can also try  ggalt's x-spline function.

Comment: Please post reproducible data so that other contributors can provide solutions. You can paste a data structure using the `dput(DunnTib)` function.

Comment: I've shared the complete data set (700 rows) via google drive. I used `dput()` to generate a subset but felt that the problem was more evident when a larger data set is used because the points are so close.